# Package air 2.6 mobile application to native installer

Tags: mobile, installation, air, cross-platform, native

I have an application which is built on flex mobile project. I want to package it as exe(for windows) and dmg(for mac). Right now, Flex builder 4.5.1 provides option to signed Air package for installation on desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For windows, I found one tool: 
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Quick_Setup_Script_Generator

its pretty good!